# Storing a block in a variable with changing number of parameters

Tags: ios, class, variables, parameters, block

I encountered a problem or maybe its me just not knowing the appropriate way:

One of my objects is initialized with a block. Depending on the context, the block definition changes, which means, the number of parameters is not fixed and may change between f.e. between 2 and 6.

How do I set up a variable to store the block in or do I have to set up multiple variables, which I don't really want to? Is there something like "wildcarding"?

Comment: Pass a Dictionary, and inside specify the values.

Comment: Can you explain more what you are trying to achieve? How would you *call* the block if you don't know the number and types of the arguments?

Comment: ok, i'll try it out :-)

Comment: @Martin, i just do not know the number

Comment: @Jacky Boy: Thank you, works fine, good idea!

Answer (score 1):

As it helped you and in order for you to close the question:

> You can pass a Dictionary and inside specify the values.